Setting $u$ = escape velocity when calculating the maximum height of a thrown object
So, if I throw an object at some velocity $v$ at an angle θ, the maximum height reached by the object is $\frac{v^2\sin^2{\theta}}{2g}$ but, I know this isnt true. clearly in a weird way, the height reached is infinity because the object never returns, so why does this break at $v = v_e$ I also know that escape velocity doesnt depend on direction, it's more like a speed,
why can't I use it in equations like:
$S = vt + \frac{1}{2}gt^2$
also, thought id throw this in here, if I throw an object at $kv_e$ where r is the radius of the earth and $0<k<1$, is it true that the maximum height would be $\frac{k^2r}{1-k^2}$

haha very funny whoever put the topic as "homework and exercises". i thought it was a good question, anyways ‍♀️

To answer your first question: the equation you cite is derived using an approximation, this being that the acceleration due to gravity is constant. We know from Newton's law of gravitation that it actually decreases as the square of the distance between two bodies (i.e. a thrown ball and the earth).
However, in our day to day life, we encounter only heights that are insignificant compared to the radius of the earth. Therefore the difference in gravitational acceleration is also insignificant and the assumption of constant acceleration is acceptable.
But when talking about an escape velocity, we must consider the weakening of gravitational acceleration (if it didn't weaken, any thrown object would eventually return). Therefore, the approximation, and with it the formula, must fail.

Your equation:
$$ h = \frac{v^2\sin^2{\theta}}{2g} $$
applies only when $g$ is constant i.e. $g$ never changes no matter how far you get from the Earth. With a constant $g$ that is independent of distance from the earth the escape velocity would be infinite.
